# Clean way to put Bison's stack.hh, position.hh and location.hh in a different folder

Tags: c++, bison

I have a project in which a am using Bison to generate parser. Project itself is build with SCons and all of my code is written in C++. One of the things I decided on the beginning was separating code into 3 main diretories: includes, src and test, where first one could contain only *public* headers, *src* containing both implementations and *private* headers, and *test* containing just tests.

Currently this convention is broken by 3 files: **stack.hh**, **position.hh** and **location.hh**. They are automatically generated by Bison since I use it in a C++ mode. But, while I could use argument *--defines=include/namespace/parser.hpp* to set where parser's header should be placed I cannot find a way to define where those 3 files should be put, so they are saved in the same folder as *src/namespace/parser.cpp*.

I'd like to find out how to handle it cleanly. So far I came up with 2 ideas: first is to use *%define* and *api.location* to set it to currently used classes (which would prevent Bison from generating those files again) and then move those files there. The other is to reimplement *position* and *location* classes on my own and set them up with said api. One idea sound to me like a dirty hack while the other as an overkill for such a simple task.

Is there any other (clean) way to make sure that helpers used by parser will be placed in a *include* directory while *src* will contains only implementations?

EDIT:

The reason why those files (or their replacement) should be put in public headers folder is that they are being included in **parser.hpp** file generated by Bison. As a result I would not be able to compiling any file that includes parser.hpp without adding those files to list of searched folders. Currently I have to add path to source folder to includes, so that compiler can find those 3 files required only in 1 place: parser.hpp header that is generated and I have no control over it. It is inconsequent and confusing so I would like to make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently version 2.5 of Bison that I'm stuck with doesn't give me much of an option. Since 2.7 I am able to use option `api.namespace` to prevent bison from generating `position.hh` and `location.hh`. Then I could generate those files once, move them manually, and add this option. But there is no option (even in current 3.0) to prevent stack.hh from being created or  to replace it with something on my own.

So only solution I can apply now is moving those files to required location, each time bison is called by builder. It's ugly, dirty hack but it ensures consistency in the rest of the system so I will go with it for now. In SCons I implemented it like this:

```
# Directories configuration

# Main directories
fnb      = 'f_n_b/'
include  = 'include/'
source   = 'src/'


###########################################################################

# Some modules and tests

###########################################################################

# Builds parser and scanner classes

Parser_yy_URI   = fnb    +'parser.yy'
Parser_cpp_URI  = source +'parser.cpp'
Parser_hpp_URI  = include+'parser.hpp'
Scanner_ll_URI  = fnb    +'scanner.ll'
Scanner_cpp_URI = source +'scanner.cpp'

Parser_cpp = env.CXXFile(
    source=Parser_yy_URI,
    target=Parser_cpp_URI,
    YACCFLAGS=['--defines='+Parser_hpp_URI, '--verbose']
)
Scanner_cpp = env.CXXFile(
    source=Scanner_ll_URI,
    target=Scanner_cpp_URI
)

CorrectBisonInstallation = [
    env.Command(
        include+WronglyPlacedBisonHelper_hh.name,
        WronglyPlacedBisonHelper_hh,
        Move("$TARGET", "$SOURCE")
    )
    for WronglyPlacedBisonHelper_hh in Glob(source+'*.hh')
    if  WronglyPlacedBisonHelper_hh.name in [
        'location.hh',
        'position.hh',
        'stack.hh'
    ]
]
Depends(
    CorrectBisonInstallation,
    [Parser_cpp, Scanner_cpp]
)

###########################################################################

# Some modules depending on Parser and Scanner classes
```

It's far from perfect solution (using `move` during build!) but until some better one appear I'll use this one.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about where your files should go, or at least you're confusing *me*.  On one hand you say that your include/ directory is reserved for public headers and other headers should go under src/.  On the other hand, you're saying that the header files for Bison's helper classes -- which are surely private -- should go into include/ on account of not being implementation code.

Bison should be dropping those headers alongside the parser's main C++ file (you seem to confirm it does), and that seems like the right place according to one of your sets of criteria.  If you nevertheless want those headers elsewhere, then I think you'll need to copy or move them after the fact.  I do not care for SCons, but surely it allows you to write rules to achieve that.

Comment: They would be private if I would be able to compile other classes (not Parser and Scanner ones) without them. But **parser.hpp** generated by Bison includes them. AS a result I am not able to compile or link anything to parser without those files. I'll add that notice to a question post.